# Can I share a MACOS app via google drive?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have built an application for MacOS that I would like to be able to share with some friends. I have archived the application in XCode and typically used "copy" as a method of distribution. This method has been working as long as I am able to put the files onto a flash drive that I physically hand to a friend.

The issue is that I would like to be able to share this over the internet via dropbox or google drive. Unfortunately, when I do, the app does not open with an error message of "can't be opened." I have tried distributing through my developer ID and notarizing the app, this made no difference. I am sure that there is something that I am overlooking, but I have no clue what it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, when I do, the app does not open with an error message of "can't be opened."

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372084/macos-catalina-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened-you-should-move-it-to-the-t

Another trick is right click > open.

> I have tried distributing through my developer ID and notarizing the app, this made no difference.

Sounds like you have not checked the code sign errors correctly. Several scripts exist on GitHub where organisations notarise their apps. You can use them.

> I am sure that there is something that I am overlooking, but I have no clue what it may be.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82587/how-can-i-determine-if-a-certain-app-file-is-signed

> Can I share a MACOS app via google drive?

Yes, but if it's not notarised, you can add a readme file which tells them to code sign the app themselves

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343912/should-i-sign-open-source-code-myself/343934#343934

Answer (score 0):

You could try compressing/encoding it first and then uploading it to drive, Google File Stream is notorious for corrupting random files

Answer (score 0):

I recommend manually copying the app into a `.dmg.zip`   I am not sure if you can set xcode to do it automatically.

`hdiutil create -format UDBZ -fs HFS+ -srcdir /path/to/srcdir -volname MyApp_v1 MyApp_v1.dmg`

`zip MyApp_v1.dmg.zip MyApp_v1.dmg`

`srcdir` is your base folder that contains the app, *et cetera*.